# Org-mode to Markdown converter?

Tags: conversion, markdown, org-mode

I have an org-mode file that is mostly just an outline, and want to convert it to Markdown. But it is a long and big file, so is there a piece of software that can do this for me? I use Mac OS X, but am willing to do this in another OS if needed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Newer versions of org-mode (>= 8.0) can export to markdown directly:
https://orgmode.org/manual/Markdown-Export.html

But you should note that there is no menu to export to markdown by default, and you need to add the following configuration to your .emacs file such that emacs automatically loads markdown export mode:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988092/emacs-org-mode-export-markdown

```lisp
(eval-after-load "org"
  '(require 'ox-md nil t))
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like there's still some work to be done, but [this project](https://github.com/alexhenning/ORGMODE-Markdown) may meet your needs.

Comment: After installing some depedencies this project needs, I was able to export my org-mode document to markdown. Thank you very much for your suggestion!

Answer (score 4):

So, it turns out you can do this now, with the shiny new markdown exporter

http://orgmode.org/org.html#Markdown-export

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a tool to do this outside of Emacs, you should definitely look at [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/). In addition to allowing you to convert [orgdown](https://karl-voit.at/2021/11/27/orgdown/) files to a multitude of file formats, you can notably also add style to the document at the same time. In other words, just like how we split up HTML and CSS, with pandoc we can keep the design of the document separate from the content.

Comment: I like this answer because yes org-mode's Markdown-export works but source code in the output is just indented and therefore on github.com/blah/blah.md there is no syntax highlighting. However `pandoc -f org -t markdown blah.org -o blah.md` spits out code with triple backticks maintaining the language name I specified in blah.org , and so on  github.com/blah/blah.md , syntax highlighting works effortlessly.